# How to Map brightness in CSS( using filter ) from -100% to 100% using feFuncR, feFuncB, feFuncG

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend, svg-filters

What should I set the values of slope of `feFuncR`, `feFuncG` and `feFuncB` inside `feComponentTransfer` to map the brightness of an image from -100% (complete black) to 100%(complete white) with 0% having no effect.

I have tried using `filter="brightness(x)"`, it works as expected for values (0-1 or 0% to 100% i.e. it turns from a black image to a normal image), but while increasing the brightness, I expect the image to turn completely white. It does not happen even after using values as great as 10000000% for some images.

Answer (score 0):

Is the input already greyscale or is the input a color image? And what do you mean by "map the brightness" - do you want to map every input color to just two output colors: rgb(0,0,0) and rgb(255,255,255) Or do you want to alter the blackpoint and whitepoint of the image? (FWIW - the CSS brightness filter is a multiplier so if any of the color components are zero (e.g. rgb(0,34,128)) - it will never turn white.)

Assuming you have a color input and you want a posterized black and white - this is the filter you would use.

```
<filter id="posterize" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
  <feColorMatrix type="saturate" values="0"/>
  <feComponentTransfer>
     <feFuncR type="discrete" tableValues="0 1"/>
     <feFuncG type="discrete" tableValues="0 1"/>
     <feFuncB type="discrete" tableValues="0 1"/>
 </feComponentTransfer>
</filter>
```

If you want to add/substract equal amounts of brightness to each color channel, then it's easier to use feColorMatrix and adjust the fifth column from -1 to 1. The following will give you black. Change the -1 to 1 and you'll get all white.

```
<filter id="additive-brightness" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
  <feColorMatrix type="matrix" values="1 0 0 0 -1 
                                       0 1 0 0 -1 
                                       0 0 1 0 -1
                                       0 0 0 1 0"/>
</filter>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, 
I wanted to create a slider using which I can control the brightness of the image, slider having range from -100 to 100. Applying -100% should turn the image complete black and 0 should have no effect and 100 should make the image complete white.

Hence I wanted to know how should I use the filter property to achieve the same.